# Vertical tabs like in foundation docs website with zurb foundation?

Tags: zurb-foundation

How to make a vertical tabs like we have in zurb foundation doc website : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascripts.php where we have tabs and sub menu when clicking on item for example "javascript".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code from their page
it's just unordered list inside one of list elements from main navigation

```
<ul class="tabs vertical hide-on-phones">
  <li><a href="index.php">Getting Started</a></li>
  <li><a href="compass.php">Compass</a></li>
  <li><a href="rails.php">Rails</a></li>
  <li><a href="sass.php">Sass</a></li>
  <li><a href="quickstart.php">CSS Quickstart</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="components.php">Components</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="components.php">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="grid.php">The Grid</a></li>
      <li><a href="media-queries.php">Media Queries</a></li>
      <li><a href="typography.php">Typography</a></li>
      <li><a href="buttons.php">Buttons</a></li>
      <li><a href="forms.php">Forms</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="navigation.php">Navigation</a></li>
      <li><a href="tabs.php">Tabs</a></li>
      <li><a href="elements.php">Elements</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascripts.php">Javascripts</a></li>
  <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```